# Terraform upgrade from 0.15 -> 1.2.4

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I am upgrading the terraform version from 0.15 to 1.2.4 while also upgrading the azurerm version from 2.70 to 3.12.0

With this changes there are coming new resources for the sql server/database, so I had to replace all of the `azurerm_sql_***` to `azurerm_mssql_***` . With these changes there are also a few changes in the code for example `server_id` instead of `server_name` but no changes in the infrastructure. It went really smooth except when I run terraform plan it want to delete all of the old resources and replace them to the new ones which is bad because it deletes the sql servers and the databases. This leads to data loss, or I need to manually recover after it finishes.

Is there any way to prevent the deletion of the resources and just update the state file?

I tried to run
`terraform plan -refresh`
`terraform plan -refresh-only`
None of them worked, on the next run it still wants to delete the resources.
I didn't run `terraform apply` since I did not want to risk to delete any prod database.
I run on a dev environment and there it deleted the servers and recreated them.

Any idea what should I do to prevent the deletion and update the state with the resources of the new version?

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax There are a number of other similar questions and answers that can elaborate on this. Someone else will probably have a link readily available to one of them. Otherwise, we need a concrete example for a concrete answer.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to your situation but I have done things like this to manage the local tfstate
`terraform state list; terraform state rm <resource>; terraform import <new_resource>`

Comment: Have you seen the AzureRM provider v3 upgrade guide section [Migrating to New & Renamed Resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/3.0-upgrade-guide#migrating-to-new--renamed-resources)? It includes a link to some detailed instructions on how to migrate from the deprecated names to the new names.

Comment: I did exactly the same mentioned by @LHWizard which is also written in the migration, but it still want to delete but now the new resource(mssql server and db).

Comment: The plan will display why the provider wants to Delete the resources. You can observe the reasons and remediate from there.